# Maintaining complex logic integrity across tables

Tags: postgresql, view, data-modeling, materialized-views

I am designing a relational database with many complex integrity rules between tables. The way I am thinking of doing it is defining the most fundamental table, and writing views to represent the higher level concepts that arise from the fundamental tables.

For instance, imagine a bank account database, I define a concrete `transaction` table, keeping the deposits and withdraws from an account, and a view called `balance`, summing all deposits and withdraws from each account. There is also a concrete table called `liability`, registering amounts blocked in each account, so that the view `avaliable_balance` is the balance as given by `balance` minus the sum of all blocked money for the account in table `liability`. As it goes on, it becomes increasingly complex.

As the database grows, I fear something as simple as finding how much money a client can spend yields a too complex and expensive query. The alternatives are:

- Materialized views, but as I understand them, they are not updated automatically, and updating them is a costly operation that can't be done at every table change.
- Concrete tables for the views, updated automatically only via `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` triggers on the fundamental tables. But this is error prone, costly in development time, and just feels wrong, as the relations and update rules can be "easily" inferred from the views' definitions, and seems like something that should be done automatically.

Will I run into performance problems when such database grows? If yes, how can I solve it? Which is the best approach, performance wise? Is there an alternative I am not seeing?

Comment: My *preference* is for views or materialized views.  Someone else will probably argue triggers.  You can add functions to the pantheon of possibilities.  But your question is both broad ("usually approached") and a matter of opinion ("which is the best").

Comment: This problem seems too common that I thought perhaps there is simple, elegant solution I don't know about.

Comment: What actually is the problem ? Is the schema too complex ? Are queries too slow ? The question is too broad, please limit it to a specific problem, otherwise you will most likely get 5 votes "too broad" in a moment.

Comment: My feeling on this is that it is practically impossible to enforce within an RDBMS every integrity rule that the business mind can think up, and therefore it is best to stick with the basics. You also have the problem that with transactions being unable to see each other, you need to implement a per-account locking mechanism anyway in order to guarantee that a transaction can be executed. As you say, MVs in PostgreSQL cannot fast refresh on commit, so I would disregard them.

Comment: Do you have any estimate of how many transaction will occur per day, and how many users will be running those views (and how often)? Is it some sort of reporting database or actual back-end for the product?

Answer (score 0):

The question is so general that I can only give a very general answer; on another day I might vote for "too broad".

Views can be a good and a bad thing. They are good for

- abstracting an interface from the actual physical data model
- allowing a user to see only some parts of the data in a table

Your use case is the first one.

Use taste and discrimination when you define your views. Here are two guidelines:

- Don't nest your hierarchy of views too deeply. More than two levels is usually too much. Deep hierarchies of views make the model incomprehensible and make debugging very hard.
- Never forget that a view is not a table. It may only perform well in certain queries, for example with certain additional `WHERE` conditions.

The best thing you can do is to figure out at design time what kinds of queries you are going to run against the database, particularly the frequent queries. Then you can plan your views so that they perform well with those queries.

Use materialized views and other techniques that keep redundant data only if your performance requirements leave you no other way out. Often a good design is sufficient.